# why this code isn't converting decimals to binary from decimals 0 to 31

Tags: c, binary, decimal

So I was trying to convert a decimal number to binary using c. In this code every thing seems to be working well. Also this code does work for decimals from 32, 33 and go on. But this code doesn't work for decimals from 0 to 31. What's the bug in here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

    int decimal;

    printf("Enter the decimal value: ");
    scanf("%i", &decimal);
    int n, remainder;
    int i, j, k;

    for (int i = 0; i < decimal; i++)
    {
        if (pow(2, i) <= decimal)
        {
            n = i;
        }
    }

    char index[n];
    int quotient[n];

    quotient[0] = decimal;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        quotient[i + 1] = quotient[i] / 2;
        remainder = quotient[i] % 2;

        if (remainder == 1)
        {
            index[i] = '1';
        }
        else
        {
            index[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    for (int k = n; k >= 0; k--)
    {
        printf("%c", index[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apart from other things, what will happen here `quotient[i + 1] = quotient[i] / 2;` when 'i' reaches the value of 'n'?

Comment: Running your code in a debugger with a memory sanitizer/checking would probably be highly informative. And note, it doesn't "work" for values 32 and above. You just think it does because sometimes invoking *undefined behavior* appears to "work". [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/TMvnjj56z).

Comment: `decimal` is not a _decimal_ int is an `int`.  The presentation of a decimal value is a presentation function provided bt for example `printf`.  The `int` _already is binary_ because that is how computers represent _all_ objects, regardless of type.  As such your "conversion" is unnecessary and over complex - you can simply use a "walking 1" bit mask to inspect and present individual bits.

Comment: Also you have a rather convoluted method of determining the number of significant bits.  Fe2O3's answer is the sensible solution but if you must do it arithmetically then `int n = ceil( log( decimal ) / log( 2 ) ) ;`

Answer (score 0):

The number returned by `scanf()` is a bit pattern (binary) representation of the base10 value you enter.

You've got the right idea (trying to 'pick apart' those bits), but the method used is dubious and confusing.

Below is a loop of some familiar values being converted to strings of 1's and 0's.

Consider what it is doing at each step...

```
int main() {
    for( int i = 253; i <= 258; i++ ) {
        printf( "Decimal %d: ", i );

        unsigned int bitmask = 0;
        bitmask = ~bitmask;
        bitmask &= ~(bitmask >> 1); // High bitmask ready

        // skip over leading 0's (optional)
        while( bitmask && (bitmask & i) == 0 ) bitmask >>= 1;

        // loop using bitmask to output 1/0, then shift mask
        do {
            putchar( (bitmask & i) ? '1' : '0' );
        } while( (bitmask >>= 1) != 0 );

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Decimal 253: 11111101
Decimal 254: 11111110
Decimal 255: 11111111
Decimal 256: 100000000
Decimal 257: 100000001
Decimal 258: 100000010
```

Comment: Thanks sir for this code. This code is more dynamic. But I'm still stuck on that thing.(my previous code) Actually I think my logic was correct. Then where was the actual mistake happened? Can you please help me in that?

Comment: @Heckar Actually, I'm afraid I cannot help you with your implementation. Presume the number entered is 5000111. Your method would invoke a floating point function (pow) half a million times just to determine the leftmost bit that is set... Gives me a headache to think about. Good luck, though!

Comment: @Heckar `pow` is a floating point function (expensive). It makes no sense to make hundreds of "guesses" trying to determine which set bit is the highest.... To use two variable length arrays (when you know you will need 32 (or 64) elements at a maximum just adds to the complexity. Try to write clear, concise code... Your CPU will thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this, but you seem to want to use `pow()` to find the highest set bit in the incoming integer. Perhaps this will lead you to the solution you are looking for.

```
int main() {

    int n = 0;

    // generate a series of numbers as input
    for( int decimal = 1; decimal < 1000*1000*1000; decimal = decimal * 2 + 1 ) {

        // Limited of 32 bit integers INCLUDING sign bit
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {

            int guess = (int)pow( 2, i ); // make a guess with this value
            printf( "Guess %d\n", guess );

            if( guess > decimal ) { // guess now encompasses set bits
                n = i; // Found what is needed.
                break;
            }
        }
        printf( "decimal input = %d: examining %d bits\n", decimal, n );
        getchar();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here's one sample of the output of the above.

```
Guess 1
Guess 2
Guess 4
Guess 8
Guess 16
Guess 32
Guess 64
decimal input = 63: examining 6 bits
```

Note: this sort of thing will only work for positive values. It'll probably blow up if you want the bit pattern of a negative integer.

And, because you want to store an array of `quotient`, you need to dimension it to have +1 elements to avoid stepping out of bounds as you peel-off each bit through division...